# Grafana chained variables in repeating rows

Tags: prometheus, grafana, dashboard, template-variables

I have a dashboard that uses two variables:

[image: Variables on the dashboard]

`$clients` is a static list and `$running_sessions` is the result of a MySql query that uses `$clients` (something like `select id from sessions where client_id in ($clients)`).

I have a row that repeats per client defined like this:

[image: Row definition]

Inside the row, I have a panel that uses `$running_sessions` from a Prometheus data source.

```
sum without(instance) (metrics{module="XXX",category="XXX",name="RunStatus",id=~"$running_sessions"})
```

If `All` is selected for `$clients`, I get a row per client (expected), but the panel shows the sessions of all the clients, instead of the sessions of the client of the row.

I was expecting that the value of `$running_sessions` on a specific row would be computed using the local value of `$clients`.

Is there a way to achieve this?